# Is the compiler allowed to do such an optimization?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Compiler: VC++2013
Mode: Release

Story: I learned about IAT hooking. I decided to practise on ExitProcess(). I got crashes as soon as the replacement function returned. Why? Because somehow the compiler decided to think that what follows ExitProcess() will never be executed so that code was not generated. For example when I put ExitProcess() inside an if statement everything went fine. So how is this a valid optimization? ExitProcess() is inside a DLL, so the compiler couldn't even do any link-time optimizations if it wanted to. It just magically assumes that ExitProcess() will never return.

I think the compiler should not do such things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ExitProcess is defined by the documentation to never return. If you wrote a replacement function that does return, then that's you breaking the promise the documentation made, and any breakage as a result is your problem.

C++11 Standardised the notion of such functions and has a notation for them. VS does not implement this yet I believe, but there's nothing preventing them from implementing it for specific functions.

Why shouldn't the compiler assume that ExitProcess() does not return? It's pretty clearly defined to *exit the process*.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Does VC++ use some platform specific notation for such functions?

Comment: I honestly don't know. It's equally likely that they simply special-cased it inside the compiler itself. You would have to look in the header I think.

Answer (score 3):

The declaration of `ExistProcess` in the relevant header is presumably annotated with [__declspec(noreturn)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6ktzx3s.aspx). Since this is a language extension, not a standard language construct, it's within the discretion of the compiler writers (as opposed to the standard committee) whether such optimizations are allowed.